# "Undefined Index Notice" in EavAttribute.php when adding a swatch option

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav, swatches, magento-2.0.5

I am using Magento 2 and I created an attribute called `hair_color` that is of a visual swatch input type. I have inputted 140 swatch options for this attribute, but on the 141 I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: option_141 in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Model/Plugin/EavAttribute.php
>   on line 177

I am having difficulties figuring out what is the issue since I am using the admin interface to do this.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Magento CE are you using?

Comment: Confirmed it's Magento 2.0.5 CE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like problem in server settings.

Please try increase `max_input_vars` setting to 100000 and try reproduce problem.

Comment: If I find you I'll hug you. Saved my life. Thanks heaps!

Comment: this thing does not solve my problem do you have any other working solution.

Answer (score 0):

the below code work for me after Magento 2 root  .htaccess adding below code bottom.

### Add Value as required

php_value max_input_vars 60000